# How do I run the qt installation file in Ubuntu22.04?

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Qt in Ubuntu22.04, but when I try to open the 'qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run' file, nothing happens. Through the terminal, the same thing. How can I fix this?

I'm new to ubuntu and don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Have you made sure the file is executable via chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run, then run ./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run from a terminal?

Comment: it makes the file executable, and after the command ' ./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run' writes  ' /qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run: error loading shared libraries: libxcb-xinerama.so.0: unable to open a shared object file: There is no such file or directory '

Comment: Do you have the libraries installed?  Try running the following BEFORE running the installer:  sudo apt install -y qtcreator qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake cmake and then sudo apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libssl-dev libssl1.0 libgl1-mesa-dev libqt5x11extras5.  Once those are finished, run ./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.5.2-online.run

Answer (score 1):

Install missing library:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0
```